# When it comes to adding styles to onClick, when is once enough?

Tags: javascript

When it comes to adding styles to onClick, when is once enough?

Meaning, as an example.

Cursor: pointer; is in the top part, do I need to put it in the middle part  2 more times also, or is once sufficient enough? That's pretty much all I'm asking.

```
playButton4.style.cursor = 'pointer';
```

```html
    <button id="playButton4" style="display:block; width: 266px; height: 266px; cursor: pointer;background-image: linear-gradient( to right,#000000 83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, #000000 86px, #000000  174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, #000000 177px ); border: 3px solid #0059dd;"
    onclick=" 
        var button = document.getElementById('playButton4');
        var player = document.getElementById('player4');
          document.querySelector('#playButton4 .initial').style.display='none';
          document.querySelector('#playButton4 .pause').style.display='none';
          document.querySelector('#playButton4 .play').style.display='none';
        player.volume=1.0; if (player.paused) {
    playButton4.style.background = 'linear-gradient( to right,transparent 83px,#e77d19 83px, #e77d19 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #e77d19 174px, #e77d19 177px, transparent 177px ), url(\'https://via.placeholder.com/266x266\')';
        playButton4.style.boxShadow='inset 0 0 0 3px #e77d19';
        playButton4.style.border='none';
        playButton4.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
        playButton4.style.backgroundPosition = 'center'; 
        document.querySelector('#playButton4 .pause').style.display='inline-block';
        player.play();
        } else {
    playButton4.style.background = 'linear-gradient( to right,transparent 83px,#e77d19 83px, #e77d19 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #e77d19 174px, #e77d19 177px, transparent 177px ), url(\'https://via.placeholder.com/266x266\')';
        playButton4.style.boxShadow='inset 0 0 0 3px #e77d19';
        playButton4.style.border='none';
        playButton4.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
        playButton4.style.backgroundPosition = 'center'; 
        document.querySelector('#playButton4 .play').style.display='inline-block';
        player.pause();
        }">
    
      <svg class="initial" width="90" height="108" viewbox="0 -3 85 120">
        <path fill="currentColor" style="stroke: #e77d19; stroke-width:3px;color:black; " d="M81 44.6c5 3 5 7.8 0 10.8L9 98.7c-5 3-9 .7-9-5V6.3c0-5.7 4-8 9-5l72 43.3z"></path>
      </svg>
    
      <svg class="pause" style="display: none;" width="60" height="72" viewbox="0 0 16 14">
        <path d="M12.945.38l-.652.762c1.577 1.462 2.57 3.544 2.57 5.858 0 2.314-.994 4.396-2.57 5.858l.65.763c1.79-1.644 2.92-3.997 2.92-6.62S14.735 2.024 12.945.38zm-2.272 2.66l-.65.762c.826.815 1.34 1.947 1.34 3.198 0 1.25-.515 2.382-1.342 3.2l.652.762c1.04-1 1.69-2.404 1.69-3.96 0-1.558-.65-2.963-1.69-3.963zM0 4v6h2.804L8 13V1L2.804 4H0zm7-1.268v8.536L3.072 9H1V5h2.072L7 2.732z"
        fill="#1ed760 " fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
      </svg>
    
      <svg class="play" style="display: none;" width="60" height="72" viewbox="0 0 16 14">
        <path d="M12.945.38l-.652.7623zM0 4v6h2.804L8 13V1L2.804 4H0zm7-1.268v8.536L3.072 9H1V5h2.072L7 2.732z" fill="#1ed760 " fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
      </svg>
    
    </button>
    
    <audio id="player4" style="display:none;">
      <source src='' type='audio/mpeg'></source>
    </audio>
```

Comment: You should style with external CSS. Note that the HTML style attribute will override any external style not created with JavaScript. `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='external.css' />` is the most powerful external style, followed by `<style type='text/css' src='external.css'></style>`, then `<style type='text/css'>@import 'external.css';</style>`. Style like `<style type='text/css'>html,body{padding:0; margin:0}</style>` and the HTML style attribute should be avoided, as they are not cached into memory. Of course, those tags should be in your `<head></head>`.

Comment: "Note that the HTML style attribute will override any external style not created with JavaScript." What do you mean by that?

Comment: Just a comment. Inline style, otherwise known as HTML style takes precedence over other ways of styling. Of course, JavaScript style takes precedence over all other style. This is important to know because if you use the HTML style attribute then the CSS associated with that Element will be overridden. To style all of the buttons you want to show a pointer on, I would give them all an HTML class, like `class='pointer'` then in your external CSS it's like `.pointer{cursor:pointer;}`. Or if you don't want to add the HTML class, and just do all buttons: `button{cursor:pointer;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify cursor:pointer on something nested within this, it would be redundant. This should be enough (depending on separate styling that may be on children of the element you show with the cursor styling).

You would only need to add another pointer style if something nested below your top element was overriding it.

Side note: It's *generally* best to put that styling in a class and apply that class, rather than inline styling.

Comment: @If this answered your question, could you mark it as such? Thanks !

Comment: This answered my question. Thank you.